# Limit Get-ChildItem recursion depth

Tags: powershell

I can get all sub-items recursively using this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse
```

But is there a way to limit the depth? If I only want to recurse one or two levels down for example?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use this to limit the depth to 2:

```
Get-ChildItem \*\*\*,\*\*,\*
```

The way it works is that it returns the children at each depth 2,1 and 0.

---

Explanation:

This command

```
Get-ChildItem \*\*\*
```

returns all items with a depth of two subfolders. Adding \* adds an additional subfolder to search in.

In line with the OP question, to limit a recursive search using get-childitem you are required to specify all the depths that can be searched.

Comment: So awesome. I guess I've never needed to do this in PowerShell, but I know I have wished for it before in CMD.EXE.

Comment: Seems like you have to do "-path \\*\\*\\*,\\*\\*,\\*" to pull in the intermediate depths.

Comment: I tried it, yet it seems to go up instead of down. How can I use it generate a Folder Tree as in http://superuser.com/questions/258287/how-can-i-export-a-directory-structure/450031?noredirect=1 ? Thank You.

Comment: To start the recursion from the current directory, a dot needs to be added at the beginning of each path. `Get-ChildItem .\*\*\*,.\*\*,.\*` At some point, by PowerShell 5.1, Get-ChildItem now has a `-Depth` parameter.

Answer (score 101):

[As of powershell 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), you can now use the `-Depth` parameter in `Get-ChildItem`!

You combine it with `-Recurse` to limit the recursion.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 2
```

Comment: It seems that the `-Recurse` switch is optional / implied when `-Depth` is specified.

Comment: One thing I found with this that seems odd is `-Exclude` when included with `-Depth` negates the `-Depth` value.

Comment: @ssaviers The same problem happens with -Include as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, the -Depth parameter seemed to be ignored when combining with wildcards.  For example, `gci c:\*.exe -Depth 1` returns files multiple subdirectories deep.

Comment: Good to know! `gci c:\ -filter *.exe -depth 1` would probably get you what you want @GuitarPicker I don't have a windows machine to test right now however

Comment: @CharlieJoynt, no, `recurse` is needed.

Comment: @Timo I can't totally tell if you're agreeing or contradicting me but including `-Recurse` certainly makes the intention clearer. In my own testing (PS 5.1.18362.752 on Windows 10) it doesn't seem to be needed; by specifying (only) `-Depth x` I get files/folders returned up to that depth.

Answer (score 9):

Try this function:

```
Function Get-ChildItemToDepth {
    Param(
        [String]$Path = $PWD,
        [String]$Filter = "*",
        [Byte]$ToDepth = 255,
        [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0,
        [Switch]$DebugMode
    )

    $CurrentDepth++
    If ($DebugMode) {
        $DebugPreference = "Continue"
    }

    Get-ChildItem $Path | %{
        $_ | ?{ $_.Name -Like $Filter }

        If ($_.PsIsContainer) {
            If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {

                # Callback to this function
                Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path $_.FullName -Filter $Filter `
                  -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
            }
            Else {
                Write-Debug $("Skipping GCI for Folder: $($_.FullName) " + `
                  "(Why: Current depth $CurrentDepth vs limit depth $ToDepth)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2010/01/22/limit-recursion-depth-with-get-childitem/)

Comment: It actually works. Sample invocation: `Get-ChildItemToDepth -ToDepth 2` (working on the current directory)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to limit Get-ChildItem recursion depth using Resolve-Path

```
$PATH = "."
$folder = get-item $PATH 
$FolderFullName = $Folder.FullName
$PATHs = Resolve-Path $FolderFullName\*\*\*\
$Folders = $PATHs | get-item | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
```

But this works fine :

```
gci "$PATH\*\*\*\*"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function that outputs one line per item, with indentation according to depth level. It is probably much more readable.

```
function GetDirs($path = $pwd, [Byte]$ToDepth = 255, [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0)
{
    $CurrentDepth++
    If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {
        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
        {
            if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container)
            {
                "." * $CurrentDepth + $item.FullName
                GetDirs $item.FullName -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is based on a blog post, *[Practical PowerShell: Pruning File Trees and Extending Cmdlets](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/practical-powershell-pruning-file-trees-and-extending-cmdlets/)*.

Answer (score 0):

@scanlegentil I like this.
A little improvement would be:

```
$Depth = 2
$Path = "."

$Levels = "\*" * $Depth
$Folder = Get-Item $Path
$FolderFullName = $Folder.FullName
Resolve-Path $FolderFullName$Levels | Get-Item | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | Write-Host
```

As mentioned, this would only scan the specified depth, so this modification is an improvement:

```
$StartLevel = 1 # 0 = include base folder, 1 = sub-folders only, 2 = start at 2nd level
$Depth = 2      # How many levels deep to scan
$Path = "."     # starting path

For ($i=$StartLevel; $i -le $Depth; $i++) {
    $Levels = "\*" * $i
    (Resolve-Path $Path$Levels).ProviderPath | Get-Item | Where PsIsContainer |
    Select FullName
}
```

Comment: This will show all sub-folder names to the specified depth

Comment: This appears to show items **at** a given depth, not **up to** a given depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$path = C:\ # Path for the 
$depth = 0 # Indicates depth, 0 is just the base

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Depth $depth | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".extension"}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).