# Searching Windows directory for a file, only 'n' levels deep from command line

Tags: search, windows-7, directory-structure

In Windows 7, is it possible to search directories for a file or pattern, but go only 'n' levels deep?

I cannot install any external tools

The Dir /s command seems to go all the levels that may exist.  I want to limit it to just 'n' (3 or 4 ) levels, but couldn't find an option to do so.

Comment: With powershell, Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\Logs\*\*\*   -- add as many \* as levels you want to go deep -- See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly not. The default command line options do not include this option.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other commands that can be combined with this to create a .bat file that will let me do this?

Comment: Maybe `tree` together with `grep` can help. However, grep is not available by default on windows systems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I wrote a batch file to do this very thing:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set currentLevel=0
set maxLevel=%2
if not defined maxLevel set maxLevel=1

:procFolder
pushd %1 2>nul || exit /b
if %currentLevel% lss %maxLevel% (
  for /d %%F in (*) do (
    echo %%~fF
    set /a currentLevel+=1
    call :procFolder "%%F"
    set /a currentLevel-=1
  )
)
popd
```

This will list directories arbitrarily deep.

**Usage:** list.bat *"search string" [number]*

This will search for the string [number] levels deep. (This includes the current level, so 2 would search current directory and one level deeper)

Comment: Hi,  I tried it as "list.bat java 3" and "list.bat .java 3", but I don't get any output and the script exits - it comes back to the command prompt.  I have .java files at level 0, 1 and 2 ( and deeper, but was testing with 2 or 3 )

Comment: Just realised that the script is traversing the directories, and that I should add the logic for checking for a file with specific extension or the filename containing given string