# PowerShell to get Folder Owner 3 Folders Deep

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, powershell-3.0, directory

I need to get a list of all the folders owners on a shared network drive. However, I want to limit the recursion to just 3 folders deep (some of our users will create folders several levels deep, despite us telling them not to). I've found the below script, and slightly modified it to just give folder owner (it originally returned a lot more information for ACLs), but it still goes down through every folder level. How can I modify this to only return 3 folder levels?

```
$OutFile = "C:\temp\FolderOwner.csv" # indicates where to input your logfile#
$Header = "Folder Path;Owner"
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "G:\" # which directory/folder you would like to extract the acl permissions#

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $Owner = (get-acl $Folder.fullname).owner
    Foreach ($ACL in $Owner){
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + ";" + $owner
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Comment: This covers it: [Limit Recursion][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a '*' to your path for each level. For example, this should return items three levels deep under C:\Temp:

```
dir c:\temp\*\*\*
```

Here's a sample function you can use (it's written for PowerShell v3 or higher, but it can be modified to work for version 2):

```
function Get-FolderOwner {
    param(
        [string] $Path = "."
    )

    Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        # Get-Acl throws terminating errors, so we need to wrap it in
        # a ForEach-Object block; included -ErrorAction Stop out of habit
        try {
            $Owner = $_ | Get-Acl -ErrorAction Stop | select -exp Owner
        }
        catch {
            $Owner = "Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message
        }

        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Path = $_.FullName
            Owner = $Owner
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Get-FolderOwner c:\temp\*\*\* | Export-Csv C:\temp\FolderOwner.csv
```

If you're after all items up to and including 3 levels deep, you can modify the function like this:

```
function Get-FolderOwner {
    param(
        [string] $Path = ".",
        [int] $RecurseDepth = 1
    )

    $RecurseDepth--

    Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        # Get-Acl throws terminating errors, so we need to wrap it in
        # a ForEach-Object block; included -ErrorAction Stop out of habit
        try {
            $Owner = $_ | Get-Acl -ErrorAction Stop | select -exp Owner
        }
        catch {
            $Owner = "Error: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message
        }

        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Path = $_.FullName
            Owner = $Owner
        }

        if ($RecurseDepth -gt 0) {
            Get-FolderOwner -Path $_.FullName -RecurseDepth $RecurseDepth
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Get-FolderOwner c:\temp -RecurseDepth 3 | Export-Csv C:\temp\FolderOwner.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, it's nearly there, but found it only returns the information for the folders the specified levels deep. I.e. G:\\*\\*\\* will return the folder owner for G:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3 but not for the parent folders G:\Folder1\Folder2 or G:\Folder1. I'd like the folder owner for level 1, 2 and 3, not just 3!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that part. See if the addition to the answer works.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! I've modified it slightly, so you can specify the path, output and recursion as variables at the start. `Get-FolderOwner $SharePath -RecurseDepth $RecurseLevel | Export-Csv $OutFile` This way I can give to my team and tell them just to update those variables without touching anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Any help?

```
resolve-path $RootPath\*\* |
 where { (Get-Item $_).PSIsContainer } -PipelineVariable Path |
 Get-Acl |
 Select @{l='Folder';e={$Path}},Owner
```

Comment: Trying to see where to add this to my code. I've replaced everything below the "$RootPath = G:\" line, but I get an error:
`A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PipelineVariable'.`

Comment: My apologies.  -PipeLineVariable wasn't introduced until V4.