# Powershell archive multiple directories in single zip archive

Tags: powershell, filter, timestamp

UPD1 - I reworked my question to make it less vague

I'm new in Powershell and need someone advise.
I have a directories, which I need to zip, for example:

in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\STAGETEST\
        App_Config
        Resources
        bin

There are another bunch of directories in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\STAGETEST\ and I need to zip only App_Config, Resources, bin - with all subdirectories and files, keeping structure.
For this I have a script:

```
$SOURCEDIR = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\STAGETEST\" 
$SOURCEFOLDERS = "App_Config", "Resources", "bin"
Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Include "$SOURCEFOLDERS" -Directory
$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Directory
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
Foreach ($s in $SOURCE)
{
$DESTINATIONDIR = Join-path -path $SOURCEDIR -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"
```

#Check if archive already exists and delete it

```
If(Test-path $DESTINATIONDIR) {Remove-item $DESTINATIONDIR}
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $DESTINATIONDIR)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot understand, how to implement proper Get-ChildItem -include to get all necessary multiple directories?
Perhaps, is there any other approach?

Comment: When double quoting a var it doesn't get expanded, either use single quotes or omit them. But AFAIK the include option only refers to extensions not to folders. Do you want to include the timestamp in the archive name or set the file date/time?

Comment: @LotPings - Do you want to include the timestamp in the archive name or set the file date/time?
Yes, that is correct - this is a second issue in my script :)

Comment: @LotPings I want ti include a timestamp in archive name

Comment: `$dtstamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")` specify your desired format in the string.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to Get-ChildItem help:

> Include - 
>   Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are permitted.
>   The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a
>   directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

so, You need an array and -Recurse parameter

```
$SOURCEFOLDERS = @("App_Config", "Resources", "bin")
$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Include $SOURCEFOLDERS -Directory -Recurse
```

Comment: Ok, you're right with array string, but additionally to 3 needed directories, it returns a bunch of directories, that nested inside this or another unnecessary folders. https://prnt.sc/iygwei     Is there any way, to perform request only in current folder ( $SOURCEDIR = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\STAGETEST\"  ) ?

Comment: Check:

[Limit Get-ChildItem recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth)

Comment: alternatively:

Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Directory|Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "App_Config|Resources|bin"}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName