# Edit Get-DirStats.ps1 to take a depth (subdirectory) parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

As I'm new to powershell I need help to edit the popular Get-DirStats.ps1 in a way it takes a new (depth) parameter which will define how much sub-directories it will read and output stats.

Currently the code will output all sub-directories which I need to limit by depth.

This should be in powershell 2.0 as I have some windows 7 machines.

The ps1 can be downloaded here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Outputs-directory-size-964d07ff

I've learned from this thread: [Limit Get-ChildItem recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth)

That this should be a general solution: 
$Depth = 2
$Levels = "*" * $Depth

But adding this to the Get-DirStats.ps1 is giving errors.

```
# Written by Bill Stewart 
# Outputs file system directory statistics. 

#requires -version 2 

<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
Outputs file system directory statistics. 

.DESCRIPTION 
Outputs file system directory statistics (number of files and the sum of all file sizes) for one or more directories. 

.PARAMETER Path 
Specifies a path to one or more file system directories. Wildcards are not permitted. The default path is the current directory (.). 

.PARAMETER LiteralPath 
Specifies a path to one or more file system directories. Unlike Path, the value of LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. 

.PARAMETER Only 
Outputs statistics for a directory but not any of its subdirectories. 

.PARAMETER Every 
Outputs statistics for every directory in the specified path instead of only the first level of directories. 

.PARAMETER FormatNumbers 
Formats numbers in the output object to include thousands separators. 

.PARAMETER Total 
Outputs a summary object after all other output that sums all statistics. 
#> 

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path")] 
param( 
  [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="Path",ValueFromPipeline=$true)] 
    $Path=(get-location).Path, 
  [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="LiteralPath")] 
    [String[]] $LiteralPath, 
    [Switch] $Only, 
    [Switch] $Every, 
    [Switch] $FormatNumbers, 
    [Switch] $Total 
) 

begin { 
  $ParamSetName = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName 
  if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) { 
    $PipelineInput = ( -not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Path") ) -and ( -not $Path ) 
  } 
  elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) { 
    $PipelineInput = $false 
  } 

  # Script-level variables used with -Total. 
  [UInt64] $script:totalcount = 0 
  [UInt64] $script:totalbytes = 0 

  # Returns a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] object if it exists. 
  function Get-Directory { 
    param( $item ) 

    if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) { 
      if ( Test-Path -Path $item -PathType Container ) { 
        $item = Get-Item -Path $item -Force 
      } 
    } 
    elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) { 
      if ( Test-Path -LiteralPath $item -PathType Container ) { 
        $item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $item -Force 
      } 
    } 
    if ( $item -and ($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) ) { 
      return $item 
    } 
  } 

  # Filter that outputs the custom object with formatted numbers. 
  function Format-Output { 
    process { 
      $_ | Select-Object Path, 
        @{Name="Files"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Files}}, 
        @{Name="Size"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.Size}} 
    } 
  } 

  # Outputs directory statistics for the specified directory. With -recurse, 
  # the function includes files in all subdirectories of the specified 
  # directory. With -format, numbers in the output objects are formatted with 
  # the Format-Output filter. 
  function Get-DirectoryStats { 
    param( $directory, $recurse, $format ) 

    Write-Progress -Activity "Get-DirStats.ps1" -Status "Reading '$($directory.FullName)'" 
    $files = $directory | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse:$recurse | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } 
    if ( $files ) { 
      Write-Progress -Activity "Get-DirStats.ps1" -Status "Calculating '$($directory.FullName)'" 
      $output = $files | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length | Select-Object ` 
        @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}}, 
        @{Name="Files"; Expression={$_.Count; $script:totalcount += $_.Count}}, 
        @{Name="Size"; Expression={$_.Sum; $script:totalbytes += $_.Sum}} 
    } 
    else { 
      $output = "" | Select-Object ` 
        @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}}, 
        @{Name="Files"; Expression={0}}, 
        @{Name="Size"; Expression={0}} 
    } 
    if ( -not $format ) { $output } else { $output | Format-Output } 
  } 
} 

process { 
  # Get the item to process, no matter whether the input comes from the 
  # pipeline or not. 
  if ( $PipelineInput ) { 
    $item = $_ 
  } 
  else { 
    if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) { 
      $item = $Path 
    } 
    elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) { 
      $item = $LiteralPath 
    } 
  } 

  # Write an error if the item is not a directory in the file system. 
  $directory = Get-Directory -item $item 
  if ( -not $directory ) { 
    Write-Error -Message "Path '$item' is not a directory in the file system." -Category InvalidType 
    return 
  } 

  # Get the statistics for the first-level directory. 
  Get-DirectoryStats -directory $directory -recurse:$false -format:$FormatNumbers 
  # -Only means no further processing past the first-level directory. 
  if ( $Only ) { return } 

  # Get the subdirectories of the first-level directory and get the statistics 
  # for each of them. 
  $directory | Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse:$Every | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { 
      Get-DirectoryStats -directory $_ -recurse:(-not $Every) -format:$FormatNumbers 
    } 
} 

end { 
  # If -Total specified, output summary object. 
  if ( $Total ) { 
    $output = "" | Select-Object ` 
      @{Name="Path"; Expression={"<Total>"}}, 
      @{Name="Files"; Expression={$script:totalcount}}, 
      @{Name="Size"; Expression={$script:totalbytes}} 
    if ( -not $FormatNumbers ) { $output } else { $output | Format-Output } 
  } 
}
```

PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> .\Get-DirStats.ps1 "C:\Program Files" 2
Where 2 is the depth

Comment: PowerShell v2.0 does not support the parameter `-Depth` from `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Yes I know, for this reason I'm trying to implement it by using this: 
$Levels = "\*" * $Depth

Where $Depth is an int argument provided by user

Comment: First of all you have to add a new script input parameter `Depth` and after that the section inside the `process` block needs some modification.
You have to write your won locig ([take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth)).

Comment: Added the Depth param here:

`param(
  [parameter(Position=..]
    $Path=(get-location).Path,
  [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory...]
    [String[]] $LiteralPath,
    [int[]] $Depth,
    ...
)
$Levels = "\*" * $Depth
`

and assigned the value to $Levels , The problem is in concatenating the Path with Levels process



` process {
 
  if ( $PipelineInput ) {
    $item = $_ 
  }
  else {
    if ( $ParamSetName -eq "Path" ) {
 #Here is the issue
 $item = $Path$Levels
    }
    elseif ( $ParamSetName -eq "LiteralPath" ) {
      $item = $LiteralPath
    }
  }`