# Compare folders and sub-folders with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, compare, subdirectory

I'd like to compare 2 folders including a number of sub-folders with PowerShell.
So far I've used the following:

```
$Folder1 = Get-childitem "K:\Program Files\"
$Folder2 = Get-childitem "K:\Program Files2\"
Compare-Object $Folder1 $Folder2 -Property Name, Length
```

However this doesn't look into all the sub-folders
Could you please help and advise what the best way would be here?

Comment: What happens when you add the recurse flag? See similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth

Comment: Hi, may you please edit the question by selecting the code and pressing CTRL+K. It will format the code, so that it is better readable. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Adis1102 hi, I edited the question as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Tested it with -Recurse and it works

```
$folderA=Get-ChildItem "C:\Test" -Recurse
$folderB=Get-ChildItem "C:\Test - Kopie" -Recurse

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folderA -DifferenceObject $folderB -Property Name,Length
```