# batch findstr to certain depth of subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I had the below code for searching through sub directories for 2 exe files:

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion
for %%d in (c) do if exist %%d: (
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/b/s/x %%d:\autolog.exe %%d:\autorun.exe 2^>nul ^| findstr /V /C:".*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*" /C:".*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*" /C:".*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*" /C:".*\.*\.*\.*\.*\.*" /C:".*\.*\.*\.*\*"') do (
set var=%%a;!var!
))
echo %1,!var!, >>C:\test.txt
exit
```

While it works search for all subfolder (by using /s), I would like to have result returns only if it is within **4** subfolder level (e.g. c:\sf1\sf2\sf3\autorun.exe should be a valid result, while c:\sf1\sf2\sf3\sf4\autorun.exe and any finding further down the tree should be opt out and not returning as a result).

I use all wildcard combination (* | .| .*) along with "\V" in attempt to achieve it but failed.  Why does it won't work or if there are other smarter way doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres is a sample to limit to fourth folder level, using regular expressions in the findstr terms:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\ ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\') do echo %%a
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works while only showing all 4th level directory, but it actually requires to check if the specific file exists in that directory.  I failed to modify your sample to do that.  Sorry if it sounds demanding

Comment: Just an update, I actually create another pipe of findstr and it works perfectly now, thanks.

Comment: You could also use `dir "file.ext" /a-d /b /s` instead of `dir /ad /b /s`

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559986/12861751) answer. [`ROBOCOPY`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) is available since Vista, and it is a robust utility that does more than copying files.
e.g. The `/L` switch prevents it from copying; while `/LEV` allows you to copy only the top N levels of root, which eliminates one `FINDSTR`.

## Golfed

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('
ROBOCOPY "C:\." "C:\." autolog.exe autorun.exe /S /LEV:4 /IS /L /NS /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS^|FINDSTR \\.*\\.*\\.*\\
') do set "var=%%~fF;!var!"
echo %1,!var!,>>C:\test.txt
```

---

## Formatted

```dos
@echo off
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set "list="
set ^"FORCMD=^
 %__APPDIR__%ROBOCOPY.EXE C:\. C:\. autolog.exe autorun.exe^
     /S %=non-empty Subdirectories=%^
 /LEV:4 %=MAX 4 LEVels=%^
    /IS %=Include Same files=%^
     /L %=List only (don't copy)=%^
    /NS %=No Size=%^
    /NC %=No Class=%^
   /NDL %=No Directory List=%^
   /NJH %=No Job Header=%^
   /NJS %=No Job Summary=%^
|%__APPDIR__%FINDSTR.EXE \\.*\\.*\\.*\\%=MIN 4 LEVels=%" It's convenient to use delayed expansion


FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('!FORCMD!') do set "var=%%~fF;!var!"
::Due to weird expansion rules
::if VAR was undefined, it is set to '~,-1'
if DEFINED var set "var=!var:~,-1!" Remove trailing ;


>>"C:\test.txt" echo(%1,!var!,
```